# Edit files inside Resx in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resx, rider

In a .net application I need to edit an html template that I put inside a Resource file (resx).

If I edit the file from the filesystem and I build and run my application again the template remains unaffected. Even if I edit by opening it from the visual studio Resource visualizer.

The only solution I found so far is by deleting the resource from the template and add it again, also with the same name.

Is there a quicker way to mark the file as modified for the compiler to return the newer version without having to delete and recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, right-click on the resource file in Solution Explorer and select "Properties".

In the Properties window, locate the "Custom Tool" property and change its value to "ResXFileCodeGenerator".

Then save the change and rebuild the project. This should cause the resource file to be regenerated and the updated version to be used in the application.

Note that changing the "Custom Tool" property will cause the resource file to be regenerated every time the project is built, so any manual changes you make to the file will be lost.

If you need to make manual changes to the resource file and have those changes persist, you can set the "Custom Tool" property back to its original value after making the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, Custom Tool was set to ResXFileCodeGenerator by default